# GCS, only user who logged in can see images in my mosaic

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I am building a mosaic using Google cloud storage, and I store the user uploaded image in a bucket. However, to see any images, you must log in(a google account) first. I have set the bucket to public and any user who had already logged in can view the image. But I want the images to show up even if they haven't logged in. What should I do?
I store the url of the image in my database:

```py
#this part is the return function of my image upload
imageurl= 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/fortest098.appspot.com/{}'.format(mosaicLocation)

# and this is how i put my image into the database:
ImageInfo(...,image_url=imageurl).put
```

am I suppose to get a public url or something?

Answer (score 0):

By default objects uploaded to GCS are access controlled.
You can make your objects publicly readable by setting a predefinedAcl at upload time or after they are uploaded (e.g., see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/update).
You can also do this using the gsutil command:

```
gsutil acl set public-read gs://your-bucket/your-object
```

Comment: Just in addition to @Mike, the way of generate the link to [access public data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data) (see API LINK) should be as follows:
https://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME].
This link does not require authentication in order to use. It is suitable, for example, as a link in a web page, or for downloading with a command-line tool such as cURL.